# Windows Phone: How to get image source value of an image tag inside a stack panel?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I have some stack panels. And each of stack panels has an image tag. The code look like this:

```
....
<StackPanel>
     <Image Source="/Puzzle15;component/Images/Themes/Easy/p5.png" Tag="5"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
     <Image Source="/Puzzle15;component/Images/Themes/Easy/p6.png" Tag="6"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
     <Image Source="/Puzzle15;component/Images/Themes/Easy/p7.png" Tag="7"/>
</StackPanel>
...
```

I want to get image source value by using the code

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 14; i++)
{
    String s = ((Image)((StackPanel)ContentPanel.Children[i]).Children[0]).Source.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

And the result shows "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage"

Could you show me the way to get the source value?? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bms = ((Image)((StackPanel)ContentPanel.Children[i])
          .Children[0]).Source as BitmapImage;
var addy = bms.UriSource.ToString();
```

By the way, the way you are doing this is antithetical to WPF (and silverlight, WP, Modern UI, etc etc) programming.  I would strongly suggest you do some reading, some tutorials, learn what "View Model" means, and how to use Bindings.  You will be better off in the end.